# $ \int_{0}^{ \infty} \int_{0}^{ \infty} \frac { e^{-(x+y)}}{x+y} dx dy $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Question : The integral

$$ \int_{0}^{ \infty} \int_{0}^{ \infty} \frac { e^{-(x+y)}}{x+y} \mathop{dx}\mathop{dy} $$

is

(a) infinite

(b) finite but can not be evaluated in closed form

(c) 1

(d) 2 .

I tried substituting $u=x+y$ and $v=y$ that led me no where . I'm not even sure about convergence of integral .Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: tis integral as the value $1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variables substition works fine : its jacobian is $1$ but you have to pay attention to the domain shape. If $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{+2}$, $(u,v)\triangleq(x+y,y)\in T$ where $T$ is the "triangle" $\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^{+2} / v \leq u\}$.

Your integral is then
$$\int_{u=0}^{\infty}\int_{v=0}^{u}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v = \int_{u=0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{v=0}^{u}\,\mathrm{d}v\right)\frac{e^{-u}}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u $$

The integral of $1\,\mathrm{d}v$ from $0$ to $u$ is $u$ and you can get rid of the denominator.

Answer (score 5):

Let

$$f(a) = \int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-a(x+y)}}{x+y}dx \, dy$$

$$f'(a) = -\int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_0 e^{-a(x+y)} \, \,dx dy = - \left( \int^\infty_0 e^{-ax}\,dx\right)^2 = -\frac{1}{a^2}$$

$$f(a) = \frac{1}{a}+C  = \frac{1}{a}$$

$$f(1) = \int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-(x+y)}}{x+y}dx \, dy = 1$$